# How to click the MORE INFO button using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click a button on a website using Selenium.

Below are my attempts. None have worked.

```
#CSS Selector
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".more-info-button").click() 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("more-info.span.more").click() 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("more-info > span.more").click() 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.more").click() 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#more-info").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".more").click()

#ClassName
driver.find_element_by_class_name("more-info-button").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("More").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("more-info-button.trigger").click()

#Xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'More')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font[contains(text(),'MORE INFO')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/span[1]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='more-info']/span").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/span").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='more-info']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='panel']/div[4]/span").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]/span").click()
```

Screenshot of HTML:

[image]

Comment: Please share the website!

Answer (score 1):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//span[@id='more-info']
```

CSS that you should check :

```
span#more-info
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Now if it's unique try to click using one of the below technique:

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='more-info']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='more-info']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='more-info']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='more-info']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>MORE INFO</kbd> is represented within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) as follows:

```
<span id="more-info" class="more-info-button trigger">
    <span class="more">More</span>
    <span class="hide">Hide</span>
    " Info"
</span>
```

---

### Solution

To click() you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.more-info-button.trigger#more-info span.more"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='more-info-button trigger' and @id='more-info']//span[@class='more']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```